# SQL Conditional where clause for different parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing below SQL statement in stored procedure but not able to create conditional SQL where query. I am passing below input parameters to stored procedures

```
@givenDate='2019-08-08'  --Date
@boolinput1=1   --boolean datatype
@boolinput2=1   --bolean datatype
@xmonths=6      --int

select *
from employee
Where ((birthdate>=DATEADD(m, -@xmonths, @givenDate) AND @boolinput1=1) OR
      (birthdate<=@givenDate and @boolinput2=1))
```

Above condition will work for individual conditions when @boolinput1=1 and @boolinput2=0   or boolinput1=0 and @boolinput2=1

I need sql query when both conditions are true ie @boolinput1=1 and @boolinput2=1 then  below  condition to work and not or part

```
select * 
from employee
Where (birthdate>=DATEADD(m, -@xmonths, @givenDate AND @boolinput1 )
```

Comment: this is so confusing...

Comment: Either you've missed a `)`, or those are some really weird DATEADD calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your second set of conditions to be used when the "indicator" condition for the first is true, just add `AND @boolinput1=0` into the second set of conditions.

Alternatively, if this is executed in a stored procedure, you could just force the second indicator to false when then first is true before the query is even executed.

```
IF (@boolinput1=1)
   SET @boolinput2 = 0;
```

Comment: I want individual boolean conditions to work separately  and also when  both boolean conditions are true then i want only left part of condition to work and not right part

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE 
    ( birthdate >= DATEADD(m, -@xmonths, @givenDate) AND @boolinput1=1 ) 
    OR ( birthdate <= @givenDate AND @boolinput2=1 AND @boolinput1 = 0)
```

This prevents the second condition to succeed if both flags are true, which is how I understand your question.